# Take images from different location using varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a image handling application, that will take images from different location, location is  more than 1000 end points, its URLs.

The all location have lot of images, So I need to take images from all this location every time. so I beleave the better solution is keep a cache server in frond of image server, when they call image each time the requist image will cache in cache-server(varnish), so next time it will take from cache, this will avoid every time download large images.

The problem is, can we use varnish cache in frond this. Is this better solution to keep cache in this place, is it possible this in varnish cache server ? or can use any other solution ?

Comment: Varnish is definitely a good candidate. But can you explain in detail how the decision making is done on which endpoint to choose?

Comment: directly calling that URL now , end point is a image file

Comment: Do all these endpoints have different hostnames? If they don't, it's an easy setup. But if these 1000 endpoints each have their own hostname, things will get a bit more difficult.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn, Yes.. its are different end point , different hostname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varnish is an excellent candidate when it comes to web acceleration. But there will be challenges.

### Open source will not be able to satisfy your case

Unfortunately, your use case cannot be satisfied with the open source version of Varnish.

The challenge you'll have is keeping track of every backend. The fact that you have thousands of images, each with their own endpoint, using a different hostname, will make your backend definitions complicated.

For every hostname, a backend should be defined, which would lead to massive amounts of backends. When starting up Varnish, each backend is tested, which could lead to a very slow startup time.

### Dynamic backends in Varnish Enterprise

Varnish Enterprise has a module called ["dynamic backends"](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/goto/), which allows you to define backends on the fly. You can compose the hostname of a backend at runtime, and interface with other systems to determine that hostname.

This allows you the flexibility you need, and will reduce the overhead.

Here's a simplistic example of the *goto* module that handles dynamic backends:

```
vcl 4.0;

import goto;

sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    set bereq.backend = goto.dns_backend("my.hostname.com");
}
```

### On-premise or in the cloud?

If you have an on-premise, you'll need to buy a license key in order to use Varnish Enterprise, and to leverage dynamic backends.

If you're working in the Cloud, we have Varnish Enterprise machine images on AWS, Azure & GCP. These are billed by the hour, and the payments are handled by the cloud vendor.

This is cheaper, and very flexible, without any upfront payment.

### Conclusion

The feature you need is not in open source unfortunately. I'm not trying to push the sales pitch here, but the commercial version of Varnish seems like the only way you can handle that many backends.

If anything: using our solution in the Cloud will be easier on your budget.